# Why is my 'for' loop calculating by halves and finishing 2 below the target number?

Tags: javascript

I've been practicing some basic concepts and this one confused me. I typed the age 30 into the prompt and expected the console to list 22, 21, 20, 19, and 18 but it's actually going down to 16 and calculating by .5's as well. Any idea why?

```js
var age = parseInt(prompt("How old are you?"), 10);

function calcDateAge(age) {
  var dateAge = (age / 2) + 7;
  return dateAge;
}


for (i = age; i > 18; i--) {
  console.log(calcDateAge(i));
}
```

Comment: Because `29 / 2`, `27 / 2`, etc is not an integer

Comment: Ahh that makes sense, thank you. I meant for it to run the loop after each calculation. Do you know how I would do that?

Comment: give some examples of ur expected output

Comment: @MeditationsAM What are you trying to do with the code? What is your desired output?

Comment: @brodskyb I'm just trying to practice some basic javascript that I'm learning. The idea is to calculate the ages that someone would be able to date based off of the "age divided by two plus seven rule" and list every single age that someone would be able to date based off of the age they enter into the prompt. So if I enter 30, I would expect it to return 22, 21, 20, 19, and 18.

Comment: @MeditationsAM I'll add a comment below that gives you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting decimals because your divisions are not exact. To fix this do this:

`var dateAge = parseInt(age / 2) + 7;`

This will truncate your floating point number into an Integer.

Now the reason you get 16 is not because your i variable is going to 16 but your calcDateAge() function is returning 16.

E.g: when i = 18 calcDateAge(i) = 16

Answer (score 0):

```
  var dateAge = (age / 2) + 7;
  return dateAge;
```

When age is even dividing it by 2 will give you an integer, but when age is odd, it wont give you the same. It will results in n.5.
Your loop will run `the age you entered-18` times and there is no condition which states that the result should not go below 18. The condition in for loop id for the `i` and not for the result from the function. `Math.floor` will solve the .5 problem. And apply a condition so that the `dateAge` doesn't go below 18.

```js
var age = parseInt(prompt("How old are you?"), 10);

function calcDateAge(age) {
  var dateAge = Math.floor(age / 2) + 7;
  if(dateAge>=18)
  return dateAge;
}


for (i = age; i > 18; i--) {
var check=calcDateAge(i);
  if(check)
  console.log(check)
  else
  break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Division in JavaScript is a bit different. From [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp):

> JavaScript Numbers are Always 64-bit Floating Point
>   Unlike many other programming languages, JavaScript does not define different types of numbers, like integers, short, long, floating-point etc.
>
> JavaScript numbers are always stored as double precision floating point numbers, following the international IEEE 754 standard.

Here is an example of the first 3 values of i and what is being calculated:

i = 30:

- age = 30
- dateAge = (30 / 2) + 7 = 15 + 7 = 22
- prints 22

i = 29:

- age = 29
- dateAge = (29 / 2) + 7 = 14.5 + 7 = 21.5 (note that 29 / 2 includes the decimal)
- prints 21.5

i = 28:

- age = 28
- dateAge = (28 / 2) + 7 = 14 + 7 = 21
- print 21

etc.

**Update**

If you are looking to print all of the ages between (age/2)+7, you can do the following:

```
var age = parseInt(prompt("How old are you?"), 10);

function calcDateAge(age) {
  var dateAge = Math.floor(age / 2) + 7; 
  // If age is 30, this gives 30/2 + 7 = 15 + 7 = 22. 
  // If age is 31, this gives 31/2 + 7 = 15 + 7 = 22.
  return dateAge;
}


for (i = calcDateAge(age); i > 18; i--) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your help! I see what I did wrong now.